# Dealing with serialized JSV types in Android

Tags: android, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have an existing SQLite database that is generated in ServiceStack ORMLite.  It has a field that represents a property of type Dictionary in C#.

ServiceStack serializes this into the database as JSV which works fine for our current system that runs in all .NET.

I am working on using the existing databases for an Android implementation.  Mono is (unfortunately) not an option.

I was wondering if there was a way to force ORMLite to use the JSON serialization for fields outside of actually writing a custom DialectProvider.  This would allow me to easily parse the field using available JSON parsers.

Alternatively, a JSV Parser in Java would do the trick as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complex Type [Serializer used in OrmLite to serialize Complex Types](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#pluggable-complex-type-serializers) are pluggable:

```
//ServiceStack's JSON and JSV Format
SqliteDialect.Provider.StringSerializer = new JsvStringSerializer();       
PostgreSqlDialect.Provider.StringSerializer = new JsonStringSerializer();
//.NET's XML and JSON DataContract serializers
SqlServerDialect.Provider.StringSerializer = new DataContractSerializer();
MySqlDialect.Provider.StringSerializer = new JsonDataContractSerializer();
//.NET XmlSerializer
OracleDialect.Provider.StringSerializer = new XmlSerializableSerializer();
```

You can also provide a custom serialization strategy by implementing [IStringSerializer](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Text/IStringSerializer.cs).

By default all dialects use the existing `JsvStringSerializer`, except for PostgreSQL which due to its built-in support for JSON, uses the JSON format by default.

---

There is no Java implementation of the [JSV Format](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/wiki/JSV-Format) as far as I know, but we do have a [naive implementation in JavaScript](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/release/latest/js/JSV.js) which should provide a good starting point should someone wish to port it to Java.

Comment: That's what I was afraid would be the case.  I guess I'll try my hand at porting the native js implementation and see how it goes.  Thanks for the input.